# PHP наложить 2 изображения одинакового размера

Tags: php, изображения

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, но всё же.

Есть 2 изображения png размером 200х200, одно из них имеет прозрачные места.

Как наложить одно изображение на второе с сохранением прозрачности?
Пробовал при помощи imagecopymerge(), но ничего не вышло.

Мб вы подскажете, как это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397377/combine-2-3-transparent-png-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-php

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, спасибо. Сделайте Ваш комментарий ответом, приму как вернуй

Comment: Приведите сами в ответе получившийся код и закройте вопрос. Так будет логичнее